# StageWebView Error #2044 What it means?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

I'm using a `StageWebView` in an Air iOS app and it works fine until I change my screen and needs to remove this object. When I do this I get this error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

When I run it on a PC it doesn't happen, just on iOS.

Does anyone know why this error is fired? It's annoying especially during debugging because it keeps firing the error several times.

Comment: I think that you are trying to load a content from an url which is not reachable from your iOS.

Comment: It's weird because the load works normally when I open the screen that has the webview. But when I close the screen that I get this error.

Comment: If there is no problem to get content, you can just add a `try` and `catch` to avoid that.

Comment: If you are trying to load a local file, you'll have to handle it differently on mobile since apps are sandboxed and the URL you are trying to input is likely relative to your app and not absolute.